Rotation of Pauli Vectors with $SU(2)$ reproduces the $SO(3)$ matrix. but do all $SU(2)$ matrices reproduces $SO(3)$?
So we can write the $SU(2)$ matrices multiplication as this.
$$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta^*&\alpha^*\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}z&x-iy\\x+iy&-z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha^*&-\beta\\\beta^*&\alpha\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}Z&X-iY\\X+iY&-Z\end{bmatrix}$$
now is this always rotation ($SO(3)$) provided that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ which makes them $SU(2)$.
and therefore we can rotate Pauli vectors with the help of $SU(2)$ and we know that Pauli vectors are like 3d vectors so we are effectively rotating the 3d space with the help of $SU(2)$ instead of $SO(3)$.
edit:-
and so we then can imagine Pauli spinors present within the geometry which just rotate by $SU(2)$ operation on them.

Actually, the question is unclear. Just a remark. SU(2) is an abstract group, SO(3) too. Actually you speak of a particular representation of SU(2). The same is true for SO(3). But there are many different representations. Which representation do you mean (there are many)?

So, Basically. My question is. The equation that is written in the question can be rewritten. as $$M\begin{bmatrix}x\y\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}X\Y\Z\end{bmatrix}$$
where M dependes upon $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
so, if $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ then is M a SO(3) matrix?

Of course M is a real orthogonal SO(3) matrix. Can you sharpen your question? Your top formula is the adjoint rotation of an adjoint (hence real) generator in a popular formula parameterizing this by use of complex doublet SU(2) matrices., in a confused language. They could be, of course, in any rep of SU(2), but why bother? In the doublet rep, group elements can be evaluated directly from the exponential of Pauli vectors. What is your question?

yea so we can say that for every SU(2) we definitely get a SO(3) .
if that is the case then my question is answered. I had a dought weather there exists some SU(2) such that M does not turn out to be a SO(3). which by looking at your comment  does not seems to be the case.

Linked.

Hint: a real 3-vector $\vec r=(x,y,z)^T$ is mapped, in your complex doublet SU(2) illustration to "Pauli vectors",
$$
\vec r \mapsto \vec r\cdot \vec \sigma,
$$
in the fundamental of the su(2) Lie algebra, (but of course, it could be dotted to generators $\vec T$ in any representation, of any dimension.)
In your doublet representation, you may likewise map your SU(2) group matrix to the conventional Pauli doublet representation,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta^*&\alpha^*\end{bmatrix}=\cos\theta +i\sin\theta ~\hat n \cdot \vec \sigma = e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma},
$$
where you can work out the relation of $\vec \theta$ to complex unimodular $(\alpha, \beta)$.
You should then be able to check that, for  $\vec R=(X,Y,Z)^T$,
$$
M^{ij}=\tfrac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr}(\sigma^i e^{i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma} \sigma^j e^{-i\theta \hat n\cdot \vec \sigma}), \leadsto \\
R^i= M^{ij} r^j,
$$
possibly up to signs.
The 3-by-3 matrix M turns out to be real orthogonal, so, then in the adjoint of SU(2) and SO(3).

ok so it turns to be real orthogonal but how to confirm that it is a rotation and not reflection?

I haven't thought about it, but take the determinant. Many of these statements are trivial to verify for small rotations, near the identity.

So every SU(2) does gives rise to SO(3). since determinant becomes 1, as I checked

So Just an analogy I am making here.
like how the $SU(2)$ maps to $SO(3)$ and double covers it.
we can say that $SL(2,C)$ maps to $SO^+(1,3)$ and double covers it ryt?

WP.
